# The delete button never return or redirect (never responds)

Tags: php, laravel

First I had to click on a delete button but it returns nothing, I don't know why.

It must go to a delete function on `invoicesController.php` file and do whatever I want to do.

This is my invoices controller to return all invoices:

```
public function index()
{
    $invoice = invoices::all();

    return view('invoices.invoice')->with('in', $invoice);
}
```

And this is my blade table:

```html
<table id="example" class="table key-buttons text-md-nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">#</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">رقم الفاتورة</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">تاريخ الفاتورة</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">تاريخ الاستحقاق</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">المنتج</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">القسم</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">الخصم</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">نسبة الضريبة</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">قيمة الضريبة</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">الاجمالي</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">الحالة</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">ملاحظات</th>
            <th class="border-bottom-0">العمليات</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @php
            $a=0;
        @endphp
        @foreach ($in as $i)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $a++ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->invoice_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->invoice_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->due_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->product }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ url('invoiceDetails') }}/{{ $i->id }}">{{ $i->section->section_name }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $i->discount }}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->rate_vat }}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->value_vat }}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->total }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if ($i->value_status == 1)
                        <span class="text-status">{{ $i->status }}</span>
                    @elseif($i->value_status == 2)
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $i->status }}</span>
                    @else
                        <span class="text-warning">{{ $i->status }}</span>
                    @endif
                </td>
                <td>{{ $i->note }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('in.edit' , $i->id) }}">edit</a>
    this is the issue                                       
                    <form action="{{ route('in.delete' , $i->id) }}" method="get">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $i->id }}">
                        <button type="button">delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my delete function from `invoicesController`:

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

My `web.php`:

```
Route::post('in/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoicesController::class, 'delete'])
    ->name('in.delete');
```

Comment: check your route, define get method, and in the web.php route post method.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, change your `web.php` route from `post` to `delete`:

```php
Route::delete('in/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoicesController::class, 'delete'])
    ->name('in.delete');
```

Second, change your form `method` from `get` to `POST`:

```html
<form action="{{ route('in.delete', $i->id) }}" method="POST">
```

And lastly, after that exact `<form>` tag and before `@csrf`, add a new blade directive that will "simulate" you are sending this form as `DELETE`:

```html
<form action="{{ route('in.delete', $i->id) }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
```

You can read more about [`@method` here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#method-field).